# How can I include silverlight content in wordpress?

Tags: silverlight, wordpress

I tried to include silverlight content in my blog post. But wordpress is striping out many tags. Even I tried using 'text only editor' of wordpress, but of no avail.

Answer (score 2):

I found it out. Plugin required: http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/silverlight-for-wordpress/. Passed few parameters & boom, I was able to pull in silverlight on my wp blog.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest instead providing an image link to your Silverlight content and then hosting it on another location. This will also give your users a preview of your Silverlight content without requiring them to download the full application until they choose to.

Comment: In fact that is what I'm doing it. But it is not as fun as showing the actual content in the blog

Answer (score 0):

You can't; WP restricts the HTML which is allowed in your blog to safe tags which means that there is no way to have active content in wordpress.com blog (which is also explained in the FAQ and the usage agreement).

This is to protect users of your blog against malicious code which has hit Facebook and MySpace badly in the recent years.

Comment: Sorry, there is no such restriction. Here is a link to a Silverlight DeepZoom app on our WP blog: http://blog.hitechmagic.com/?p=380

Comment: Sorry, misunderstanding: I was talking about wordpress.com. If you run your own WP site, you can do what you want. :-)